# Webapps Folder Missing in Spring Boot Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a Maven project in Spring Boot. It is is working fine i am able to access the application on port 8080 on browser. Now i want to have jsp page which can used as a Index page but under my project i can't find WEB-INF folder is missing.

I am new in Java , could you please help me how i can add a jsp page and css page in this project. Below is my POM.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>dt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>DT</description>
    <parent>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL tag lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Currently i can see below folders only in my eclipse :

[image: Eclipse Structure]

**Controller class**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping("/index")
      public String home(){
        return "First Spring Boot";
      }
}
```

Comment: Expand the _bottom_ src folder in your image - can you then drill down into "src/main/webapp"?

Comment: @NotaJD i don't see any such folder

Comment: This may shed some light: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html notably Section 29.4.5. If you clone the Sprint Boot repo there's a spring-boot-sample-web-jsp project in there. Might have to use war packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened for me, I added a jsp file, after I run the application, I noticed the folder is showing empty.

**Solution** Right-Click on the Webapp folder/main (or whichever folder is displayed as empty) -> Show in -> as Project Explorer -> Click